# Heroku not POSTing files to server

Tags: post, heroku, discord.js

I have written a discord bot that essentially will download a file and then reupload it to streamable. The problem is that once it deploys to Heroku it will be able to download the file but it does not upload the file to streamable. All the bot does is POST the video to streamable with some auth. I have the bot working on my EC2 instance but I want to move it to heroku. I am using the node request module to post the data

Comment: I dont think heroku have instance service like amazon ec2 :<

Comment: This sounds like an error inside your application, do you see / log any errors?
Are you seeing timeouts in the heroku dashboard? (heroku has a hard 30-seconds limit for requests)

Comment: @DenisCornehl there are no errors, my app just doesn't allow outbound traffic for some reason.